# ListView - Custom Adapter - CursorIndexOutOfBound Exception

Tags: android, android-listview, custom-adapter

Android 2.3.3

I am using a Custom Adapter to fill a listview. Each row in a listview has 3 textviews(Custom Layout), that are filled from the data retrieved from database.

The problem is, the data is being displayed correctly, the first time. But when I scroll down and then scroll up the listview again, I get the following exception.

```
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 7 requested, with a size of 7
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:580)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:214)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:41)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at com.mobilevoiceapps.advancedvoicecalculatorfree.History$MyCustomAdapter.getView(History.java:111)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.widget.HeaderViewListAdapter.getView(HeaderViewListAdapter.java:220)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:1588)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:695)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.widget.ListView.correctTooLow(ListView.java:1445)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.widget.ListView.fillGap(ListView.java:672)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.widget.AbsListView.trackMotionScroll(AbsListView.java:4176)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:2609)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.widget.ListView.onTouchEvent(ListView.java:3677)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:3885)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:903)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:942)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1750)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1131)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2096)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1734)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRoot.java:2200)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1884)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:878)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:636)
03-17 08:55:37.789: E/AndroidRuntime(574):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here is the code that I am using...

Retrieving from Database..
    public Cursor retrieve_history()
        {

```
        c = db.rawQuery("select * from history", null);
        return c;
    }
```

Custom Layout - ListView Row

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Count"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:text="Number"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="22dp"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:gravity="center" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ll2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.80"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Result"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Result"
            android:textColor="#316DA2"
            android:textSize="22dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtView_History_Expression"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Expression"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Custom Adapter

```
class MyCustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return c.getCount();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        LayoutInflater li = getLayoutInflater();
        convertView =  li.inflate(R.layout.history_row, null);

        TextView cnt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_History_Count);
        TextView exp = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_History_Expression);
        TextView res = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtView_History_Result);

                cnt.setText(String.valueOf(count));     
                System.out.println(cnt.getText().toString());

                expression = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("expression"));
                result = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("result"));

                if(!c.isAfterLast())
                {
                    c.moveToNext();
                    count++;
                    //c.moveToFirst();
                }               


                exp.setText(expression);
                System.out.println(exp.getText().toString());
                res.setText(result);
                System.out.println(res.getText().toString());


        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Thanks in Advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try making use of the

```
 c.moveToPosition(int position);// Move the cursor to an absolute position.
```

inside the getview method so that you can set data in listview rows properly..

Comment: Now, the exception is gone, but when the listview is displayed for the first time, the first row is being repeated twice and the last entry is not being displayed and when I scroll down and up again, the last entry is being displayed at the top.

Comment: You are facing this issue because you are not using Holder to reuse the convertview object..

Please go through this link for understanding the use of View Holder class

http://www.jmanzano.es/blog/?p=166